# Log4j 2 - Programatically setting Level and Resetting it back

Tags: java, log4j2

I am able to change the log level of Log4j 2 programmatically through this way and it works perfectly,

```
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    AbstractConfiguration absConfig = (AbstractConfiguration) context.getConfiguration();
    LoggerConfig currentLoggerConfig = absConfig.getLogger(loggerName);
    LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
    AbstractConfiguration absConfig = (AbstractConfiguration) context.getConfiguration();
    LoggerConfig currentLoggerConfig = absConfig.getLogger("");
    if (currentLoggerConfig != null) {
        currentLoggerConfig.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
    } else {
        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = new LoggerConfig(loggerName, Level.ERROR, true);
        absConfig.addLogger(loggerName, loggerConfig);
    }
    context.updateLoggers();
```

Now I would like to reset the root level to its original without restarting the server. I tried "LoggerContext.reconfigure ()" , but I am seeing only ERROR not the INFO(which is the default in the config file).

Can some one help me out How to set the level back to Original as in the  Config File (log4j2.xml)?

Comment: You need to save the level of the root logger before you change it. When you want to set it back just use the same logic you have above to reset it to the saved level.

Comment: Appreciate it. I implemented it the same way.